# Align Center CSS and After CSS

Tags: html, css

I have code below :

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
.primenu {
  display: block margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.primenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.primenu li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.primenu li:after {
  content: "/";
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="primenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.asp">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code show:

[image]

Why menu not center althought I was write margin :0 auto; ?

So I want it show:

[image]

How to fix it ?

How to delete :after in last item or add :before only for first item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to `.primenu` and use `.primenu li:not(:last-child):after` selector to add the `/`, if you don't want to add it to the last element.

Also, you don't need `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixes for `border-radius` and `box-shadow`.

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
.primenu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.primenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.primenu li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.primenu li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "/";
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="primenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.asp">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align` center on `.header`

```css
.header{
    text-align:center;
 height:50px;
 width:50%;
 margin:0 auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 box-shadow:         0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;}
.primenu {
 display:block
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100%;}
.primenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.primenu li {
    display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.primenu li:after{
  content:"/";
 color:#ccc;
 margin: 0 10px 0 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <div class="primenu">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```